# Ordering a HashMap

Tags: java, android, sorting, vector, hashmap

Good evening.

I need to organize an HashMap, and it is something like this:

private HashMap < String , Vector < Task > >  tasksOrdered = new HashMap < String , Vector < Task > > ();

Each "Task" is a made class with 3 attributes:

- Name of Person;
- Hour;
- Discipline;

I know that with that HashMap i can group Tasks by hours into vectors, just by setting the tasks hours as key, and adding those vectors, or instances if there are existing vectors.

My question is, how can i order those vectors by name of person?

An example of what i want:

[1]: Table https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4134140/Untitled.png

Hope it helps :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can order by person name like this:

```
SortedMap<String, List<Task>> taskMap = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, List<Task>>();
taskMap.put(task.getPerson().getName(), task);
```

Comment: wouldn't LinkedHashMap just use insertion order (or access order if that constructor is used)?

Comment: Also, you suggest using the Task as the key, but it is the value in your example. I agree with your code of Map<String,List<Task>> (but your answer doesn't reflect that), but maybe use a TreeMap to order by name?

Comment: Well, this solution was perfect for my problem! Thank you duffy for your support ;).

Answer (score 0):

HashMap doesn't give you any ordering. However, I am not sure if you are really interested in sorting?

It seems like you want to group tasks based off of name? You can do the same by inserting the persons name into the hashmap to grab the vector. If you want to retrieve them ordered by name, you can grab the `keyset()`, call `java.util.Collections.sort()`, and then retrieve the vectors in order.

Comment: The idea is to sort the keys of the first collection "i", and >>>>inside<<<< of each value of that "i" collection, order the collections by their keys also

Comment: I already chose the solution that better fit my problem. Check Duffy tip :). However, i want to thank you for your support! :).

Answer (score 0):

Key = task and value = name of person

Collections.sort(Vector, new Comparator() 
{

```
        @Override
         public int compare(Vector o1, Vector o2) {
             return Collator.getInstance().compare(o1.getvalue(), o2.getValue());
         }
    });
```

Just psuedo, a bit of  tweaking might be needed.

Comment: I already chose the solution that better fit my problem. Check Duffy tip :). However, i want to thank you for your support! :).